# Is there a way to get inspect element highlight on ie11?

Tags: internet-explorer

I am quite surprised I didn't see this question asked but I couldn't find any.

When I "inspect element" on ie11, passing my cursor on the divs won't make the elements highlight on my screen.

Is there a way (fix, module ...) to have it ?

The only link I found on google sent me on a "Inspect Element Will Not Highlight Element in DOM Explorer for ..." deprecated link :
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/3303680/

Is it not possible on ie ?

Many thanks !

Comment: Did you activate _DOM element highlighting_ (embedded squares upper left or Ctrl+Shift+I)?

Comment: Oops ! No, I didn't. I was surprised the feature wasn't present, I knew it would be that simple. Thanks a lot !
I think I can't accept your answer since it is a comment and not a answer. Could you please post it so I could accept it as the right answer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Activate *DOM element highlighting*. Note the `⧈` *squared square* icon (2nd upper left) or by pressing keyboard combination  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> as demonstrated in the following partial screenshot:

[image: DOM element highlighting]